# How to set permissions for a temporary queue?

Tags: jms, jboss7.x, wildfly, hornetq

We are implementing a request/reply mechanism using JBoss 7 and HornetQ. We create a temporary queue using javax.jms.Session.createTemporaryQueue() and set it to the request message using Message.setJMSReplyTo(). Our client picks up the replyTo destination and tries to send the reply, but it fails with "SEND-permission denied" for the hornetq user we are using.

We would like to provide the correct permissions for our hornetq user, but this requires a address to which the permissions apply. But since we are working with temporary queues, the address is unclear! So, the question is: what is the address of a temporary queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging we have found that the addresses of temporary queues made by HornetQ implementation of Java Messaging Service is: jms.tempqueue

So, you can give permissions to a hornetq user by adding it to the 'temps' role and add the following xml to the standalone.xml of JBoss:

```
<security-settings>
  <security-setting match="jms.tempqueue.#">
    <permission type="send" roles="temps"/>
  </security-setting>
</security-settings>
```